# How can the software of an Amazon Smart Plug be updated?

Tags: amazon-echo

I have two Amazon Smart Plugs. Per Amazon, the Latest Software Version is  102000009. My Plugs show 1000015. My devices will work for a very short time before becoming unresponsive. I'd like to update the software to see if that resolves the problem but I can't find anywhere where that is possible. None of the Amazon instructions make sense. Is there a way to force the plugs to update their software?

Comment: what are the amazon instructions? ... which part is unclear?

Comment: The Amazon instructions are to just leave it alone for a few hours and it will update itself. I’ve done that and it doesn’t happen.